# How to include files other than *.py in a module?

Tags: python, pip, python-module, file-extension

I am trying to build a python 3 module.
I want the module to read content from a `.txt` file.
(My use case is that the `.txt` file is a Jinja2 template. But let's ignore that for now.)

When I install the module with `pip`, I find that only the `.py` files get copied over, and the `.txt` file is ignored.

Why is this?

### MWE

For simplicity, I've avoided using Jinja2. I'm just trying to read a file and return it.

#### Files

File tree:

```
* mymodule/
  * mymodule/
    * __init__.py
    * file.txt
    * main.py
  * setup.py
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='mymodule',
      version='0.3',
      description='Test for stack overflow MWE',
      license='Proprietary',
      author='Matthew Davis',
      url='https://example.com',
      author_email='nobody@example.com',
      packages=['mymodule'],
      install_requires=[],
      zip_safe=False)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .main import main
```

**main.py**

```
import os

def main():

    this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    fname = 'file.txt'
    print(f"Looking for file {fname} inside {this_dir}")

    print(f"Files in {this_dir}: {os.listdir(this_dir)}")

    with open(os.path.join(this_dir, fname),'r') as f:
        content = f.read()

    print("It works!")

    return content
```

**file.txt**

```
Here is my file.
```

#### Steps

Using python 3. (I'm doing it inside a virtualenv.)

`pip3 install ./mymodule`

```
import mymodule
mymodule.main()
```

#### Expected behavior

`mymodule.main()` returns `"Here is my file."`

#### Actual behavior

```
>>> mymodule.main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/repo/workload/env/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mymodule/main.py", line 2, in main
    with open('file.txt') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
```

When I look at the directory in that traceback:

```
ls /home/ec2-user/environment/repo/workload/env/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/mymodule/
```

I see only

- `__init__.py`
- `main.py`
- `__pycache__`

So it's not just a matter of where paths are relative to. 
The file I need simply wasn't copied across during installation.

If I rename `file.txt` to `file.py` (and change `fname` accordingly), it works.
(As in, `mymodule.main()` returns a string which matches the contents of `file.py`)
This is not a satisfactory workaround though, because I don't want to name non-python files with `.py`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the solution is to modify `setup.py` with:

```
setup(
    ...
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={'':['*.txt']}
)
```

[link](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files)